# BFS traversal of a linked list trie tree in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, trie

I have been studying the `trie` data structure according to the Kend D. Lee "Data Structures and Algorithms With Python" book. There the trie is implemented using two pointers inside every node of the tree: the `follows` and the `next` pointers (as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOy16.png), the `follows` pointer is in yellow and the `next` pointer is in red).

And I have successfully implemented this structure:

```
class Trie:
    @staticmethod
    def __insert(node, item):
        # Recursive insert function
        # If the key is empty, return None as the empty node.
        if not item:
            node = None
        elif node is None:
            node = Trie.TreeNode(item[0])
            node.follows = Trie.__insert(node.follows, item[1:])
        elif item[0] == node.item:
            node.follows = Trie.__insert(node.follows, item[1:])
        else:
            node.next = Trie.__insert(node.next, item)
        return node

    @staticmethod
    def __contains(node, item):
        # Recursive search function
        if not item:
            return True
        if node is None:
            return False
        if item[0] == node.item[0]:
            return Trie.__contains(node.follows, item[1:])
        return Trie.__contains(node.next, item)


    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self, item, nxt=None, follows=None):
            self.item = item
            self.next = nxt
            self.follows = follows

    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None

    def insert(self, item):
        self.start = Trie.__insert(self.start, item)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return Trie.__contains(self.start, item)
```

The question is, how can I implement the BFS traversal algorithm on this trie? The standard BFS algorithm assumes that we need to put children of every node in a lookup queue, but how can I get all the children of the node of this type of trie?

Comment: Typically, you don't traverse a trie like you would a tree, where each node contains a specific piece of data. In a trie, internal nodes represent common prefixes of "leaves" (although an internal node could also be a "leaf" if a common prefix is, itself, a data item).

Comment: That photo is a little peculiar because it seems to suggest `crat` and `crdog` are words in the dictionary. Or am I misinterpreting? If I am misinterpreting, how would you add `clip` with only two pointers on the `c` node?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Well, as I understand only yellow pointers point to the symbols inside a given word. So the three in the photo contains only `cow`, `cat`, `rat`, `rabbit` and `dog`

Comment: Ah, I see. I was reading it as `cow` and `coat`. The red pointers are essentially a linked list of the next possible letters

Comment: As @chepner mentioned BFS isn't really clear with a trie since you need to traverse into the structure before you get a complete word. Is there a particular order you need returned by the lookup? You can but all the branches for the next pointers in a queue and then descend into them recursively. This will give you an order of `['cat', 'cow', 'rat', 'rabbit', 'dog']` thought.